# How to send current date time to Rest Api with put request in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am using axios in react js to send data in put request. it was working perfectly but when I tried to send current datetime with put request its giving me error .

```
Bad Request: /buyer/OrdersAPI/14/
[03/Oct/2021 14:19:44] "PUT /buyer/OrdersAPI/14/ HTTP/1.1" 400 132
```

I have to post current date and time to rest api date time field

**My code**

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/buyer/'
})
```

```
updateOrderStatus = async(id,status) => {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('status',status );
        data.append('orderStartTime',Date())
        await api.put(`OrdersAPI/${id}/`, data);
        this.getNewOrders();
    }
```

if I console.log(Date()) its giving me `Sun Oct 03 2021 14:28:59 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)`

Comment: try to convert it to `json` like this `new Date().toJSON()`

Comment: Try convert date using moment and covert into the depending backend api receive timestamp format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you pass a `Date` object so to fix that you need to convert it to `json` format like this

```
new Date().toJSON()
```

this will return a result like this

```js
console.log(new Date().toJSON())
```